# How can I fix this python script that I'm using to insert line breaks and some characters into a long code?

Tags: line-breaks, python-3.11

I wrote this python script and named it "line breaks.py"

```
# Set the line number to start processing from
start_line_number = 300

# Set the positions where line breaks need to be inserted
break_positions = [1, 0, 0]

# Set the number of line breaks to insert at each position
num_breaks = 1

# Open the input file for reading and the output file for writing
with open('E:\Downloads\Wikipedia\draft data set.txt', 'r') as input_file, open('final data set.txt', 'w') as output_file:
    # Loop through each line in the input file
    for i, line in enumerate(input_file):
        # Write non-modified lines to the output file
        if i < start_line_number or (i - start_line_number) % 4 != 0:
            output_file.write(line)
            continue

        # Insert the desired number of line breaks at each position
        new_lines = []
        for j, pos in enumerate(break_positions):
            new_line = "|-" + line[:pos] + '\n' * num_breaks + "|-" + line[pos:]
            new_lines.append(new_line)

        # Write the modified lines to the output file
        output_file.write('\n'.join(new_lines))
```

I'm using the script to insert 1 line break at every successive 4th line and then to insert the characters `|-` at the new successive 5th line generated by the line break.

Problem is that the script is not properly editing the code for some reason.

Input code looks like:

```
! 2020-10-20
| 6177159
| mpac3.2 
|
! 2020-10-01
| 6166863
| mpac3.2 
|
! 2020-09-20
| 6160933
| mpac3.2 
|
! 2020-09-01
| 6151185
| mpac3.2 
|
! 2020-08-20
| 6144071
| mpac3.2
|
```

Output code should look like:

```
! 2020-10-20
| 6177159
| mpac3.2 
|
|-
! 2020-10-01
| 6166863
| mpac3.2 
|
|-
! 2020-09-20
| 6160933
| mpac3.2 
|
|-
! 2020-09-01
| 6151185
| mpac3.2 
|
|-
! 2020-08-20
| 6144071
| mpac3.2
|
```

Actual output code looks like:

```
! 2020-10-20
|-|
|- 6177159

|-
|-| 6177159

|-
|-| 6177159
| mpac3.2 
|
|-
|-!
|- 2020-10-01

|-
|-! 2020-10-01

|-
|-! 2020-10-01
| 6166863
| mpac3.2 
|
|-|
|--

|-
|-|-

|-
|-|-
! 2020-09-20
| 6160933
| mpac3.2 
|-|
|-

|-
|-|

|-
|-|
|-
! 2020-09-01
| 6151185
|-|
|- mpac3.2 

|-
|-| mpac3.2 

|-
|-| mpac3.2 
|
|-
! 2020-08-20
|-|
|- 6144071

|-
|-| 6144071

|-
|-| 6144071
| mpac3.2
|
```

Comment: Would it still be correct if you added your new line before each line that started with a `!` (excluding the first one)?  That seems like it would be easier to code.

Comment: @ScottHunter   I think that's exactly I'm trying to do. Or perhaps I'm incorrectly interpreting what you mean. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Have your code check to see if a line starts with `!` to determine if a new line needs to be added before it; then write the current line.  No need to use `new_lines` at all.

Comment: @ScottHunter   I have only begun learning python a little bit, so I don't how to make the script check which lines start with `!`. What do you mean by "writing the current line"? Which instances of `new_lines` do I have to delete? Do I have to make any other edits to the script?